# React-redux doesn't set mapDispatchToProps into props

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Can you help to undestand why my container doesn't transfer dispatch prop `saveInfo` into component?

My container:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import AddCarWashForm from './../components/carwash/subComponents/AddCarWashForm.jsx'
import {addInfo} from './../actions'

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
return {
    saveInfo: (info) => {
        dispatch(addInfo(info))
    }
}
}

const AddCarWashFormContainer = connect(
    null,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(AddCarWashForm)

export default AddCarWashFormContainer
```

Here is part of AddCarWashForm.jsx

```
export default class AddCarWashForm extends React.Component{

static contextTypes = {
    saveInfo: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
```

And when I execute this code, I see in console: `Warning: Failed context type: Required context 'saveInfo' was not specified in 'AddCarWashForm'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mapping to props, not to context. Define it as a `propType` instead and it'll work as you expect it.